# Gaussian Density Function with features that may have zero standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, density-function

I am trying to create an anomaly detection code using features that sometimes have constant values and therefore do not fall in a normal distribution curve.  For example, if I am looking at tcp traffic coming from a particular port . If my sample observed only collects tcp traffic for the same port , though the sample size is large enough , my std deviation is 0.  Is it ok to ignore such feature while calculating the Gaussian density function ?.  How does it effect the other precision of the algorithm ?. when the model is used against a live traffic feed which has random distribution of port number, how would it behave?

thanks a lot for your help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Features not being normally distributed should not be an issue.
2. "features with zero standard deviation" = "constants"; their effect will either be perfectly captured by the constant term in the model or equivalently of no use if you're already sweeping out means. i.e. not only can they be ignored, they should be ignored.